# Windows api programming with c: undefined reference to OpenJobObject

Tags: c, windows, winapi

i am trying to write a short program which allows me to terminate a windows job object by its name. Here is the (shortend) code of file TerminateJobObject.c:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x600
#endif

#define JOB_OBJECT_TERMINATE 0x0008

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>



LPTSTR jobObjectName; 
HANDLE jobObj; 

int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]){
    jobObjectName = argv[0];    
    jobObj = OpenJobObject(JOB_OBJECT_TERMINATE,FALSE,jobObjectName);
    TerminateJobObject(jobObj,0);

}
```

I get the following error when compiling with "gcc TerminateJobObject.c -o TerminateJobObject":

```
TerminateJobObject.c: In function 'main'
C:/<...>:TerminateJobObject.c:(.text+0x62):undefined reference to 'OpenJobObject'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand why the linker can't resolve OpenJobObject. TerminateJobObject is linked correctly and is also from the windows api.

What i tried so far:

- Compiler: gcc, clang
- Different versions for _WIN32_WINNT (0x500,0x600,0x601)
- Different OS: Windows 7 and Windows server 2008
- "OpenJobObjectW" and "OpenJobObjectA"
- Defining WINVER

I am not very experienced with c and windows api and can't find anything on this problem, so it would be great if somebody could point me in a direction.

Api reference: [OpenJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Bumped for the effort before coming here. Yeah, its been that bad a day on SO. Best of luck. Odd as it sounds, turn on verbose-linking and make sure `Kernel32.lib` is actually being pulled in. Finally, though it should make no difference, `0x0600` rather than `0x600`

Comment: Since its a linker error, you need to concentrate on ensuring that Kernel32.lib is being linked too, as WhozCraig mentions.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your Input! I tried 0x0600 without effect. I am actually not sure how to ensure kernel32.lib is loaded but a quick google research told me that it is allways included and necessary for gcc. I tried compiling with -v and the ouput is most confusing. Existing directories are ignored and non existend are searched. But I found something interisting: winbase.h from c:/mingw/include (which is included via windows.h) is missing the OpenJobObject function while for example the TerminateJobObject is present. I am pretty sure that this is the problem. I will focus on that.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: If you are not very experience with C/the Windows API you may wish to choose a tool that is more appropriate: [Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) is available free of charge, and is compatible with the Windows SDK out of the box.

Comment: Search all the include files and see if you can find OpenJobObject.  It may simply have gotten left out.  If so, you can write the definition yourself: download the Windows platform SDK from Microsoft, and find the definition for OpenJobObject.  Compare the definitions for a few other functions in Microsoft's headers to those in the MinGW headers to see how they are changed, then do the same thing to OpenJobObject.  Once you've gotten it working, you can even post it as an answer to your own question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The Problem was/is that the header file winbase.h of mingw32 (which is included via windows.h)  is missing the function definition for OpenJobObject as Harry Johnston suspected.

I added the following lines to  .../mingw/include/winbase.h

```
#define OpenJobObject __MINGW_NAME_AW(OpenJobObject)
WINBASEAPI HANDLE WINAPI OpenJobObjectA (DWORD dwDesiredAccess, WINBOOL bInheritHandle, LPCSTR lpName);
WINBASEAPI HANDLE WINAPI OpenJobObjectW (DWORD dwDesiredAccess, WINBOOL bInheritHandle, LPCWSTR lpName);
```

Which i found in the winbase.h from [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)

Next I changed the call to "OpenJobObjectA" and now it works. :)
Thanks for the help!

Edit: As Hans Passant pointed out a cleaner way would probably be to migrate to mingw-64 or something else.

Comment: I hope you realize that this is something you *are* going to regret.  Hacking the headers like this has a knack for creating "only compiles on my machine" projects.  Best to put it in your source code, wrapped by #ifndef OpenJobObject.  Switching to mingw-w64 is the sustainable solution.

Comment: I don't agree. The c-code of the programm is actually fine and not "only my machine" since the windows api supports OpenJobObject and so should any header implementing it. Thats why I decided to go with the api change. In fact one could see it as a fix (even if only local). If I write another programm using OpenJobObject it will work as it should instead of again adding additional defs. I agree on the part of switching to mingw 64 but since it runs on a dedicated virtuall machine for a certain project it's not necessary. I will add a part about migrating for clean solution.